# PHP - Auto login to another page

Tags: php, ajax, curl

How to automatically log on to another site without leaving the current page? Predefined username and password. Hiding fields display only button to logging. After clicking on the button, but not to leave the current site. I am sorry for my English.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="test" content="test">
  <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body> 

<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="http://www.streamuj.tv/login">
<p>
<label for="name">Uživatel:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="username" size="22" tabindex="3" id="name" class="logintext" />
<br />
<label for="password">Heslo:</label>
<br />
<input name="password" type="password" class="logintext" id="password" tabindex="4" size="22" />
<br />
<a href="http://www.streamuj.tv/recoverpassword" title="Forgot!">Zapomněli jste heslo?</a><br />
<input type="hidden" name="action_login" value="Přihlásit se" />
<input type="image" src="http://www.streamuj.tv/images/login.gif" tabindex="5" class="loginbutton" />
</p>
</form>

  <iframe src="http://movies.sosac.to/cs/embed?video=75794&id=10416&affid=177519&width=640&height=360" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pass your session from another page.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another hidden input that is the URL of the current page. Then your login script can redirect back to the current page

```
<input name="URL" type="hidden" value="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
```

Just put that in your form.

Finish your login script with a redirect to that post value

Comment: Please an example of how to do it? absolutely no idea

Comment: Please how to create:  login script with a redirect to that post value ?

Answer (score 0):

outcome:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="test" content="test">
  <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body> 

<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="http://www.streamuj.tv/login">
<p>
<label for="name">Uživatel:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="username" size="22" tabindex="3" id="name" class="logintext" />
<br />
<label for="password">Heslo:</label>
<br />
<input name="password" type="password" class="logintext" id="password" tabindex="4" size="22" />
<br />
<a href="http://www.streamuj.tv/recoverpassword" title="Forgot!">Zapomněli jste heslo?</a><br />
<input type="hidden" name="action_login" value="Přihlásit se" />
<input type="image" src="http://www.streamuj.tv/images/login.gif" tabindex="5" class="loginbutton" />
<input name="URL" type="hidden" value="<?php echo 'http://www.test.cz/test.html' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
</p>
</form>

  <iframe src="http://movies.sosac.to/cs/embed?video=75794&id=10416&affid=177519&width=640&height=360" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```

Or...?